# How to have multiple sheets automatically populate master sheet as data comes in

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to have multiple sheets populate into one master sheet in google sheets. I have figured out how to populate multiple sheets from the master sheet using the `=filter()` function. However I am unable to figure out how to do it the other way around. Essentially I am trying to track call bookings for our team and am using an external program to automatically populate cells when calls are booked. I have a "master sheet" with all the calls booked for the team, then individual sheets to track calls booked by each rep. I have it so the external program populates the master sheet and then the filter function populates the personal rep sheets automatically, but I cant figure out how to do it the other way around (have multiple individual sheets populate the master sheet automatically as the individual sheets get populated). Is this possible? And if so how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details like add a sample data of the source sheets and the expected result in the master sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The setup you describe exposes you to the risk of formula results getting misaligned with manually entered data. See [Lance's explanation of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649).

One solution is to *not* use multiple tabs, but have everyone edit the master sheet directly. Use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) in the master sheet to let multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit the data without disturbing each other.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.